# Using Solve without introducing extra variables

Tags: equation-solving, pure-function

First post here. I've tried searching for an answer for this for a few days now, but it seems the search terms (solve, slot, etc) are too generic to be helpful. I'm struggling with understanding how to use `Solve` (and related functions) without adding unnecessary variables.

First, code that works. I will use an ultra simple example to illustrate the general issue.

```
vector1 = {1, 2, 3};
vector2 = {-5, 10, 3};
Module[{a1, a2, a3}, 
  Flatten @ Values @ Solve[vector1 + {a1, a2, a3} == vector2, {a1, a2, a3}]]

(*{-6, 8, 0}*)
```

What I am trying to do is write the above code without the use of the `Module` construct. I tried this:

```
Flatten[Values[Solve[vector1 + {#1, #2, #3} == vector2, {#1, #2, #3}] &]]
```

> Values::invrl: The argument Values[Solve[vector1 + {#1, #2, #3} == vector2, {#1, #2, #3}]&] is not a valid Association or a list of rules. >>*

However, the Solve does not execute, leading the Values to toss an error. I have also tried moving the & around to various positions in the brackets. Curiously, removing the & altogether does successfully execute - but every other time I accidentally use # without & I get errors from Slot, and when I do this the #'s are lit up in a scary pink color.

```
Flatten[Values[Solve[vector1 + {#1, #2, #3} == vector2, {#1, #2, #3}]]]

(*{-6, 8, 0}*)
```

It seems to me that using `Solve` without additional scoping constructs should be possible if all I need is to extract the values. Can someone point me towards an explanation of how this is working?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The usual way to do this is `{a1, a2, a3} /. 
 First@Solve[vector1 + {a1, a2, a3} == vector2, {a1, a2, a3}]`. Note that is doesn't 'use' a1, a2 and a3 in the sense that they are entered in the global namespace.

Comment: I gather the point is to get the numerical values without introducing at some stage new symbols? In this example there is the "obvious' `vector2-vector1` but of course that isn't a general approach, just one for this special case.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Interesting. I guess the reason I was trying to do it with #,&, was that it seemed to provide "two way" protection against scoping problems. In your approach, it seems that if we do have global rules for the variables we will still be in trouble. To be fair, this can be avoided by not being sloppy so this might be moot; I'm only trying to understand why it can't be done using the Slot[] construct.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, exactly. The actual problem I am working through right now is a bit more complex, but I was trying to err on the side of readability.

Comment: You could use the symbols `\[FormalA]`,`\{FormalB]` etc. that never can have values.

Comment: I think the `\[FormalA]` approach (possibly in `Array`) suggested by @Sjoerd C. de Vries is a decent compromise. The safe way to avoid name space issues is exactly what you first showed, using `Module` (coupled with the variable replacement @Sjord indicated in an earlier comment, before returning a result, so the `Module` local variables are not leaked). I agree it is slightly cumbersome but do not have a better scoping mechanism to suggest.

Comment: I wonder if something like this will work in your use-case: `With[{vars = Array[C, Length@vector1]}, Flatten@Values@Solve[vector1 + vars == vector2, vars]]`. -- Just saw Daniel's comment. He probably means the same thing but with `\[FormalA]` instead of `C`.